# Is it possible to customise the ‘fixed’ controls at the top of Control Center?

Tags: ios, control-center

iOS 11 provides the ability to customise the lower toggle controls in Control Center (show/hide and rearrange) from Settings → Control Center.

Is it possible to customise the other controls at the top of Control Center, showing/hiding or rearranging toggles and controls?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, if you're on iOS 11.1 to 11.1.2 inclusive. Tested myself on iOS 11.1.1. A reminder that you perform this at your own risk.

1. Install FilzaEscaped from https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/7lisma/release_filza_with_root_access/
   This works with any method of writing outside the sandbox (so FilzaJailed too) but I have not tested other methods myself.

   1. Download the first IPA from the post.
   2. Download Cydia Impactor from http://www.cydiaimpactor.com.
   3. Open Impactor and connect your device over USB.
   4. Drag the downloaded Filza IPA to the Impactor window and follow the prompts. If you use 2FA on your Apple ID, you will need to generate an app password.
2. In Filza on your device, navigate to `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ControlCenterServices.framework/` and open `DefaultModuleOrder~iphone.plist` with the text editor.

   1. Filza starts in /var/mobile by default, so use the back button to navigate to root (/) first.
   2. When in the correct folder, tap the ⓘ on the right of the file, then Share at the top-right, then choose Text Editor.

      [image]
      [image]
3. Move all strings from the fixed array to the user-enabled array.

   Select all the strings, cut and paste them into the bottom array.

   Below is an example DefaultModuleOrder~iphone.plist with all components controls moved to the user-enabled array.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>fixed</key>
       <array>
       </array>
       <key>user-enabled</key>
       <array>
           <string>com.apple.control-center.FlashlightModule</string>
           <string>com.apple.mobiletimer.controlcenter.timer</string>
           <string>com.apple.control-center.CalculatorModule</string>
           <string>com.apple.control-center.CameraModule</string>
           <string>com.apple.Home.ControlCenter</string>
           <string>com.apple.control-center.ConnectivityModule</string>
           <string>com.apple.mediaremote.controlcenter.nowplaying</string>
           <string>com.apple.control-center.OrientationLockModule</string>
           <string>com.apple.control-center.DoNotDisturbModule</string>
           <string>com.apple.control-center.DisplayModule</string>
           <string>com.apple.control-center.AudioModule</string>
           <string>com.apple.mediaremote.controlcenter.airplaymirroring</string>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
4. Respring. Rebooting will do it and is probably the easiest way if you're unfamiliar with other methods of just restarting SpringBoard.
5. In Settings → Control Center, re-enable the disabled standard controls if you still want them and customise their position as you wish!

   [image]
   [image]

Comment: So, jailbreaking your phone? Is it OK if I (or someone else) makes this perfectly clear at the top? (I didn't know until I read a bit farther down and saw stuff about Cydia.)

Comment: @seaturtle Well, it’s jailbreak in the sense of r/w to root, but there’s no Cydia or code injection or other things which make up what is commonly referred to as a jailbreak. Cydia Impactor is a Mac app for interacting with iOS and Android devices, completely unrelated to Cydia except in name (and author hence the name). I’m not sure what there is to say, it’s not lowering the security of the device like a jailbreak.

Comment: Huh. Interesting! I wonder how it does that—maybe writing directly to the internal storage.... (: